# Why don't content changes appear on front end?

Tags: nodes

I'm new to Drupal and have been asked to update a page's content. Thought this would be easy, but I'm having trouble.

I login, click on Content, find the page I want to edit and click Edit. I make changes to the content (just text) and click 'Save'. I navigate to the page I changed and refresh but nothing has changed.

I tried clearing both my browser's cache and Drupal's to no affect.

I double checked the URL and it matches.

I reloaded the page(node?) on the back end to confirm it had saved my changes, which it did.

How do I actually update the content of a page?

Comment: Do you see the edited content if you re-edit the node after saving? Or do you see the original content? If you are seeing the new content, you have some sort of caching turned on that is not refreshing. If you see the old content, then it means your changes aren't being saved.

Comment: Yes, the edited content remains after saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found I was saving it as a **draft**, not as **published**.

[image]